# Shared_ptr custom deleter

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl, smart-pointers

I need to do custom deleter for shared_ptr. I know that this can be done in a similar way:

```
std::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface>(Surf_return_f(), MyDeleter);
```

But I would like to make them in the style of my custom deleter for unique_ptr:

```
struct SDL_Surface_Deleter {
    void operator()(SDL_Surface* surface) {
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    }
};

using SDL_Surface_ptr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, SDL_Surface_Deleter>;
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the style of my custom deleter for unique_ptr"?

Comment: To make it look something like this:
using SDL_S_ptr = std::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface, SDL_Surface_Deleter>;
 
I would like to be able to use my type, without having to specify MyDeleter every time when creating a variable.

Comment: Deleters are different for shared_ptr and unique_ptr. unique_ptr stores the deleter directly in the pointer so different deleters have different pointer types. Usually this is a problem because you can't have different deleters in the same pointer type. shared_ptr stores it on the heap, so it doesn't have that problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to define a type alias that means "`std::shared_ptr` with my deleter type". There's no such thing, because `std::shared_ptr` has a type-erased deleter (the deleter is not part of the type).

Instead, you could create a custom version of `make_shared`:

```
template <class... Args>
std::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface> make_sdl_surface(Args&&... args) {
    return std::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface>(new SDL_Surface(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
                                        SDL_Surface_Deleter{});
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Unlike a `unique_ptr`, the deleter for a `shared_ptr` is not part of the type. You must pass the deleter to the constructor of the `shared_ptr`.

You could wrap it in a function instead:

```
std::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface> make_shared_surface(SDL_Surface* surface)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface>(surface, MyDeleter);
}
```

and then call `make_shared_surface(Surf_return_f())`.